# RPM-GPG-KEY error while doing 'yum update' / 'yum install'

Tags: installation, updates, fedora, yum, fedora-21

While I was trying to update my fedora release I got the following error:

> GPG key retrieval failed: [Errno 14] curl#37 - "Couldn't open file /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-fedora-x86_64"

Therefore my update could not finish. I was also not able to install anything using yum due to the same error.

I'm running of Fedora 21 (recently updated from Fedora 19 using fedup).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at the differens of the files `fedora-updates.repo` and `fedora-updates.repo.rpmnew` in the directory `/etc/yum.repos.d/`

I notiched that the `$releaseserver` varialble was missing in `fedora-updates.repo`

So I changed all the lines from

> gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-fedora-$basearch

to

> gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-fedora-$releasever-$basearch

After that I could update without any problems.

Comment: Thanks, this is the root cause in my situation. I backup some modified .repo files longtime ago, then when upgrading to a new release (still, longtime ago), it started reporting this error.